# Xamarin - Error when trying to read JSon

Tags: c#, php, android, json, xamarin

I want my Android app to be able to get information from a site using Json and I'm using the Rest API to send and recieve that information, however things don't work as intended.
It gives me a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` and the debug output is as follows:

```
Forwarding debugger port 8842
Detecting existing process
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/HomecheckApp.dll
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/RestSharp.MonoDroid.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
[art] Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
[monodroid] Using override path: /data/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__
[monodroid] Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8842,server=y,embedding=1
[Mono] Image addref mscorlib[0x41dd99b8] -> mscorlib.dll[0x60df5ac8]: 1
[Mono] AOT module 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly mscorlib[0x41dd99b8] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/HomecheckApp.dll'.
[Mono] Image addref HomecheckApp[0x5aa78f38] -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/HomecheckApp.dll[0x5aa782d8]: 2
[Mono] Assembly HomecheckApp[0x5aa78f38] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/HomecheckApp.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-HomecheckApp.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/HomecheckApp.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-HomecheckApp.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/HomecheckApp.dll'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/HomecheckApp.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/etc/mono/assemblies/HomecheckApp/HomecheckApp.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/RestSharp.MonoDroid.dll'.
[Mono] Image addref RestSharp.MonoDroid[0x5aa79e60] -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/RestSharp.MonoDroid.dll[0x5aa79218]: 2
[Mono] Assembly RestSharp.MonoDroid[0x5aa79e60] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/RestSharp.MonoDroid.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-RestSharp.MonoDroid.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/RestSharp.MonoDroid.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-RestSharp.MonoDroid.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/RestSharp.MonoDroid.dll'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp/files/.__override__/RestSharp.MonoDroid.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/etc/mono/assemblies/RestSharp.MonoDroid/RestSharp.MonoDroid.config'.
[monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46080
[Mono] Image addref Mono.Android[0x5aa7aaf8] -> Mono.Android.dll[0x5aa79f80]: 1
[Mono] Assembly Mono.Android[0x5aa7aaf8] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module 'Mono.Android.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-Mono.Android.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/Mono.Android.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-Mono.Android.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x5aa7aaf8] -> mscorlib[0x41dd99b8]: 2
[Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
[Mono] DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_lref_log_new'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_lref_log_new'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_lref_log_new'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_lref_log_delete'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_lref_log_delete'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_lref_log_delete'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gref_log'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gref_log'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gref_log'.
[Mono] Image addref System.Core[0x5f2e2958] -> System.Core.dll[0x5f2e1f70]: 1
[Mono] Assembly System.Core[0x5f2e2958] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module 'System.Core.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Core.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Core.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Core.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x5aa7aaf8] -> System.Core[0x5f2e2958]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Core[0x5f2e2958] -> mscorlib[0x41dd99b8]: 3
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gref_log_delete'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gref_log_delete'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gref_log_delete'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing'.
[monodroid] Xamarin/Android Trial Mode Active
[OpenGLRenderer] Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
[Atlas] Validating map...
[libEGL] loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
[libEGL] loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
[libEGL] loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
[OpenGLRenderer] Initialized EGL, version 1.4
[OpenGLRenderer] Enabling debug mode 0
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref HomecheckApp[0x5aa78f38] -> Mono.Android[0x5aa7aaf8]: 2
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref HomecheckApp[0x5aa78f38] -> mscorlib[0x41dd99b8]: 4
[Mono] Image addref System.Json[0x61398b60] -> System.Json.dll[0x614b24a8]: 1
[Mono] Assembly System.Json[0x61398b60] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module 'System.Json.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Json.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Json.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Json.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref HomecheckApp[0x5aa78f38] -> System.Json[0x61398b60]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Json[0x61398b60] -> mscorlib[0x41dd99b8]: 5
Loaded assembly: System.Json.dll [External]
[Mono] Image addref System[0x614bf570] -> System.dll[0x614dd030]: 1
[Mono] Assembly System[0x614bf570] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module 'System.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/eu.COMPANY_NAME.homecheckapp-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref HomecheckApp[0x5aa78f38] -> System[0x614bf570]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System[0x614bf570] -> mscorlib[0x41dd99b8]: 6
Loaded assembly: System.dll [External]
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x5aa7aaf8] -> System[0x614bf570]: 3
Thread started:  #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
        [Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/libc.so'.
        [Mono] DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/libc.so'.
        [Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libc.so' ('/system/lib/libc.so').
        [Mono] Searching for 'gettid'.
        [Mono] Probing 'gettid'.
        [Mono] Found as 'gettid'.
        [Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
        [Mono] DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
        [Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
        [Mono] Searching for '__android_log_print'.
        [Mono] Probing '__android_log_print'.
        [Mono] Found as '__android_log_print'.
        [MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
        [MonoDroid] System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
        [MonoDroid] at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00078>
            [MonoDroid] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x0006b>
                    [MonoDroid] at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18
                        [MonoDroid] at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
                        [MonoDroid] at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71
                        [MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.64d78430-69a4-4af6-bd73-cd5a21882790 (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0003b>
                            [art] JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable
                            [AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
```

The activity that handles the Json sharing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HomecheckApp {
    [Activity(Label = "LoginActivity", MainLauncher = true)]            
    public class LoginActivity : Activity {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);
            EditText email = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editEmail);
            EditText password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editPassword);
            Button loginButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.loginButton);
            loginButton.Click += async (sender, e) => {
                string url = "http://homecheck/appapi/finduser";
                JsonValue json = await FetchUserAsync(url);
            };
        }

        private async Task<JsonValue> FetchUserAsync(string url) {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            using(WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync()) {
                using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                    JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());
                    return jsonDoc;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And finally the action in the MVC controller:

```
 public function finduserAction() {
    $this->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response = array('name' => 'test', 'version' => '1.0');
    $this->view->json = json_encode($response);
}
```

What appears in the view:

[image]

If I type a different `string url` that returns Json (For example http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two) it works, so maybe the problem resides somewhere in the controller ?

Comment: This is still the same issue as in your previous question.  The output clearly shows a "Name Resolution Error".  If this is a locally hosted service, try specifying the IP of the server instead of the name.

Comment: [MonoDroid] System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure, the URI host you are trying to pull from is not resolving.... localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have already mentioned, the device you are debugging your app on is unable to resolve "http://homecheck/appapi/finduser", since it doesn't know the host homecheck.

Probaby you are running your API application locally. Try to deploy it to a public server or setup your local DNS to route homecheck to the machine you are running you API application on.

If you can provide some information abour your setup, e.g. are you using a real android device, what web server are you running your API application, we can probably help you resolve your problem.